# What does 'require' mean in this statement of Danto's view on (institutional) art?

Tags: postmodernism, art

According to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

> The groundwork for institutional definitions was laid by Arthur Danto, better known to non-philosophers as the long-time influential art critic for the *Nation*. Danto coined the term “artworld”, by which he meant “an atmosphere of art theory.” Danto’s definition has been glossed as follows: something is a work of art if and only if (i) it has a subject (ii) about which it projects some attitude or point of view (has a style) (iii) by means of rhetorical ellipsis (usually metaphorical) which ellipsis engages audience participation in filling in what is missing, and (iv) where the work in question and the interpretations thereof require an art historical context (Danto, Carroll). Clause (iv) is what makes the definition institutionalist. The view has been criticized for entailing that art criticism written in a highly rhetorical style is art, lacking but requiring an independent account of what makes a context art historical, and for not applying to music.
>
> https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/art-definition/#InsDef

What does 'require' mean here?

I totally see how some interpretations **require** a historical art context: in as much as some interpretations *use* that context. So does 'require' just mean contingently **involve**?

---

Music doesn't fit the bill, and are there any other arts that don't? I seem able to understand, however superficially, e.g., **literature**, without its (or art's) history, in a way that any interpretation of the literature must, i.e. parse or utter sentences in a language.

So does Danto's claim amount to the fact that some interpretations, and so art works, are more historical, more art: a continuum of types (art and non-art)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Danto, "art" is *art* by virtue of context. That's what makes his theory "institutionalist."

It's not a continuum or a spectrum between art and non art. The relationship between a piece of art and a piece of art history is one of **equivalence**. That's what is meant by saying Danto "requires" the art-historical context.

Danto's *Transfiguration of the Commonplace* is probably the best starting place to explore his theories, if you find them of interest.

Comment: i might agree: but with the emphasis on 'require' rather than 'context'. sociologist i guess.

Comment: your 1st paragraph: i disagree... nothing in any philosophy is truly "unrelated" surely. thanks for the last paragraph, do you have a source?

Comment: sorry, what am i trying to express? you've lost me. citing an entire book to make a claim (that i don't disagree with!) is unhelpful. though: why use 'require' there (in the SEP) as well as 'iff' as with the other clauses?

Comment: ah ok, thanks. if *possible* do prove yourself right. cheers

Comment: i voted down merely for the reason that your answer distorts my question. probably my fault, i'll ask on meta. cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97599/discussion-between-chris-sunami-and-another-name).